# About the word "agitate"

Tags: suffixes

I learned that "ag" means "do" or "act", and "-ate" is a suffix which represents this is a verb.

Then what does the "it" mean?
Is it just a simple connection part that means nothing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are making the "etymological fallacy". You are breaking down a word into its roots and supposing that you can derive its meaning from that.

There is a Proto Indoeuropean root "*ag-" which meant "to drive, draw out or forth, move" and can be found in various modern words:  "act", "agent", even "essay".

In the case of agitate, it is derived quite directly from the Latin *agitare*, (the "-ate" ending is a form of the Latin infinitive verb ending *-are* via a past participle *-atus* and French).  And *agitare* is a frequentive of *agare*. So the "it" is part of a Latin verbal form, indicating repeated or intense action. The actual etymology before Latin of this verbal form is uncertain, it's probably derived from some kind of Italic past participle, but none of this was written down.

This same "it" or "t" can be seen in words and "habit" and "dictate" (dicitare).

But make no mistake.  No native speaker needs any of this to understand the word.  The word is "agitate" and the Proto Indoeuropean and Latin elements are not known (at least not by this native speaker) without reasearch. You **cannot** understand a word as being a combination of roots and affixes.  Its meaning is determined by current use, not by etymology.

Comment: What a brilliant answer!

Comment: To be honest, it was all found on wiki-{pedia,tionary} and etymonline, and it really belongs on [english.se] rather than here.

Comment: It would probably be closed on ELU for "do your research first".